# Logger Begin Scope is not working for me! .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, ilogger

So this is my logging configuration:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File("C:HotelServiceLog.txt")
        .CreateLogger();

    //Log.Logger = Loggers.NewSerilogLogger(configuration);

    try {
        Log.Information("Starting up");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
    }
    finally {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

And I'm just trying to do this from a controller method

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ExpediaRegionsResponse>> GetRegionDescendantsById([FromBody] ExpediaRegionsRequest request) {
    try {

        using (_logger.BeginScope("Controller Scope")) {
            _logger.LogInformation("Controller processing");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

But this is what I'm getting in the logs

```
2020-12-07 12:09:26.511 -05:00 [INF] Controller processing
2020-12-07 12:09:26.529 -05:00 [INF] Controller processing
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the content in your `BeginScope`, you must to [structured logging](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-include-scopes-when-logging-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) first.You can see more details in this article.

> Some of the most popular options are to store the logs in Elastic Search with a Kibana front end, or to use Seq. The Serilog logging provider also supports structured logging, and is typically used to write to both of these destinations.

You are using serilog, here is an example using Seq structured.

1:Download [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq).

2:At the Visual Studio Package Manager Console type:

```
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.Seq -DependencyVersion Highest
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.Console
```

3: In your logging configuration:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            //......
            .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
            //......
```

4:Run your project and to your `GetRegionDescendantsById` action.The visit URL `http://localhost:5341`.

You can see the details [here](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/using-serilog).

Test Result:
[image]